# How to remove | sign from text using re.sub in python

Tags: python, python-re

i am working on text files and in large amount can any one tell me how can i remove | sign by using re.sub and then want to remove only numaric data like 1 and 0.6271 not T123. I think T123 is alpha numaric

> page_data=1|0.6271|bacs|T123|Biologically Active Substance

```
 page_data =re.sub(r"|", '  ',page_data)
```

Comment: page_data =re.sub(r"\|", '  ',page_data) <== can you try this?

Comment: thanks Mitra its worked. God bless you and thanks you once again.

Comment: please tell me how only numaric data like 1 and 0.6271 not T123. I think T123 is alpha numaric now

Comment: page_data=1 0.6271 bacs T123 Biologically Active Substance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to escape the `|` character.

```
import re
page_data = '1|0.6271|bacs|T123|Biologically Active Substance'
re.sub(r"\|", " ", page_data)
```

Prints:

```
1 0.6271 bacs T123 Biologically Active Substance
```

EDIT:

To get the "numbers" out of the string try this:

```
import re
page_data = '1|0.6271|bacs|T123|Biologically Active Substance'
[i for i in re.sub(r"\|", " ", page_data).split() if not i.isalpha()]
```

Output:

```
['1', '0.6271', 'T123']
```

Comment: please tell me how only numaric data like 1 and 0.6271 not T123. I think T123 is alpha numaric now

Comment: page_data=1 0.6271 bacs T123 Biologically Active Substance

Comment: i want to get only  page_data = 'T123  Biologically Active Substance'     out of page_data=page_data = '1|0.6271|bacs|T123|Biologically Active Substance'

Comment: page_data = 'T123 Biologically Active Substance'  required output